# How can I access a shared Exchange mailbox with IMAP (over telnet)?

Tags: exchange-2003, telnet

I have an Mailbox which multiple users have access to, it works fine for me and I can add it in Outlook as an additional mailbox to my account and list all its content.

I can access my *personal* mailbox using IMAP, I'm testing it by just telneting in and LIST'ing it.

The problem is that another user trying to access it is having problems accessing it through IMAP; and I want to test if I can access the *shared* mailbox with my account - how can I do that in terms of IMAP commands?

What I am doing now is:

```
telnet mail.server
01 LOGIN user pass
02 LIST "" *
03 LOGOUT
```

Edit: If there is another way to test this, that is an equally good answer.

Comment: Be aware that using the Telnet utility is not the same as using telnet, which is a protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
telnet mail.server 143
```

143 is standard port number for IMAP service.
Then read this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189326)

Comment: Yes, that should be it. I am getting the error: Account currently disabled (no matter if I'm using the correct user name or not). Do I need to specifically enable IMAP on the mailbox?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know Exchange server configuration.

Answer (score 6):

For those not wanting to spending the time to read through the KB referenced by LG, the trick is in how you log in. Use:

> ? LOGIN *domain/username/mailboxname password*

Where *mailboxname* is the name of the shared mailbox you want to access.

Tested with Exchange 2003.